# module not found on ipython notebook

Tags: python, pip, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I have an ipython notebook which starts with

```
import sklearn
```

When I run it, I get :

```
ImportError: No module named sklearn
```

indeed if I run the following snippet on the notebook, it's not showing scikit_learn:

```
import pip
installed_packages = pip.get_installed_distributions()
installed_packages_list = sorted(["%s==%s" % (i.key, i.version)
     for i in installed_packages])
print installed_packages_list
```

However when I run the snippet from command line, scikit_learn is in the list.

I thought of a version problem (module installed for one version and not on the other one), bur both on notebook and command line, sys.version give 2.7.5

Any idea about the issue here ?

Following cel's comments:

```
ipython -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)"
```

outputs /usr/bin/python (and so does running `import sys; print(sys.executable)` directly in the notebook)

Then, `/usr/bin/python -m pip install scikit-learn`
outputs: Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): scikit-learn in /Users/MyUserName

Comment: In order to make `scikit-learn` available in `ipython` you have to install `scikit-learn` using the right `pip` executable. I would try the following: `ipython -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"`. This should print a path to a python interpreter. You then should use this interpreter and call `<path-to-interpreter> -m pip install scikit-learn` to solve your problem.

Comment: but `ipython -c "import sklearn"` gives you an error?

Comment: Nope, it seems no be working. But starting a new notebook and running "import sklearn" in it causes an ImportError.

Comment: And `import sys;print(sys.executable)` in your notebook prints `/usr/bin/python`? If so that is indeed pretty weird.

Comment: Yes, it does. I'll put that in my question as well.

Comment: The last thing I can think of is to check if `sys.path` in the notebook contains the directory where `scikit-learn` is installed.

Comment: Ok, how do I check where scikit-learn is installed  (installed by pip, right ?) ?

Comment: `python -c "import sklearn;print(sklearn)"` should print the path

Comment: Do you have multiple versions of python installed? If so you might have installed sklearn in a different version that you are trying to import it with.

Answer (score 7):

I was able to fix this error on Ubuntu by adding a cell to the top of the notebook appending the module directory to the path:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages')
```

The path to add can be found when running `pip install <something>`, (such as numpy) and it tells you where each package is installed or already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that /usr/bin/python is actually a symlink?

The better solution is that you should be running your ipython notebook from a virtualenv that contains all the modules that you need.