# Pydoop failure in Jupyter

Tags: python, hadoop, ipython, hdfs, jupyter-notebook

I have a Ubuntu O/S with HDP and iPython/Jupyter installed on the same machine.
I am able to run various commands via the Jupyter notebook using the Python2 kernel.

However I am having problems with Pydoop in the Jupyter notebook. I would like to use this library to access data in HDFS on Hadoop.
I am able to successfully run the following code in the Python command console as well is in an iPython console:

```
import pydoop.hdfs as hdfs
hdfs.ls('/')
```

However I get the following failure on the hdfs.ls command in the Jupyter notebook:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pydoop/hdfs/core/__init__.pyc in core_hdfs_fs(host, port, user)
 55             'module not initialized, check that Pydoop is correctly installed'
 56         )
---> 57     return _CORE_MODULE.CoreHdfsFs(host, port, user)

RuntimeError: (255, 'Unknown error 255')
```

I believe the error is misleading as the same command does work in a normal python and ipython console.
I tried to initialize the hdfs class with the following commands but get the same error:

```
host='zzz.zzz.zzz.zzz' <host name masked for question>
port=8020
user='hdfs'

hdfs.init()
hdfs.hdfs(host, port, user)
```

The python -V command shows that both the Jupyter notebook and Python console are using Python 2.7.3

I am able to access HDFS via the Jupyter notebook with the following command:

```
!hdfs dfs -ls /user/flume/data
```

I can also confirm that the pydoop packages are available in Jupyter ('pydoop==1.2.0') via the following script suggested in [module not found on ipython notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26930515/module-not-found-on-ipython-notebook?rq=1)

```
import pip
installed_packages = pip.get_installed_distributions()
installed_packages_list = sorted(["%s==%s" % (i.key, i.version)
 for i in installed_packages])
print installed_packages_list
```

Any help would be appreciated in fixing the module error in Jupyter.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve the issue myself by uninstalling Jupyter and rather opt to install everything (Python, iPython, Jupyter, etc) via Anaconda.

Hope that helps for anyone running into a similar issue.

I believe the issue could have been related to required libraries either not being installed or not up to date even though I ran out of time to pinpoint the issue.